# Poisson process - number of store purchases in a given time

Tags: probability-distributions

> Customers enter a store according to a Poisson Process of rate  = 6
>   per hour.
>
> Individuals who enter the shop have (independently of each other)
>   probability $\theta$ of buying something.
>
> - If exactly n people enter the shop during a certain period,
>     write down the probability that precisely k of them will buy
>     something.
> - Hence show that the probability that precisely k purchase
>     something in time t hours is
>
> $(60\theta t)^k exp(-6\theta t)\over k!$ $k=0,1,2,...$

For the first part, I think that the probability of $k$ people buying something would be $\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$ but I'm not sure how that helps me do the 2nd part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $B(T)$ is the number of users buying during the interval $T$, and $N(T)$ the number of people arriving during $T$.

For the first part the probability  of $k$ people buying something is:
$$
\Pr(B(T)=k\mid N(T)=n)=\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}.
$$
Note that you need $\binom{n}{k}$ to choose $k$ people out of $n$ people who are going to buy something.

For the second part you can use Bayesian decomposition of the probability and use the fact that $N(T)$ is a Poisson RV:
$$
\Pr(B(T)=k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(B(T)=k|N(T)=n)\Pr(N(T)=n)\\
=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}\frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n}{n!}\\
=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}\frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n}{k!(n-k)!}\\
=\frac{(\lambda\theta T)^k}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T(1-\theta))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
=\frac{(\lambda\theta T)^ke^{-\lambda T\theta}}{k!}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the intensity of PP.